# Generic Type (typescript) error TS2314 on generic function type as input parameter

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

I'm getting stuck with a type error in typescript:

this is a sample code:

```
type myFunctionType<T, U> = (t: T, u: U) => U;
const testRoutine = <T, U>(myFn: (t: T, u: U) => U) => { };
const testRoutine2 = <T, U>(myFn: myFunctionType) => { };
```

I get the following error from typescript compiler on testRoutine2

```
error TS2314: Generic type 'myFunctionType' requires 2 type argument(s).
```

testRoutine look exactly as testRoutine2 so why that error from compiler?
anybody can help?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try in this way

```
const testRoutine2 = <T, U>(myFn: myFunctionType<T,U>) => { };
```